# My spinner is invisible

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I've a problem with a spinner widget.
This is my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fondoRes"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:contentDescription="@string/par" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imaResc"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/vacia"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numInv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imaResc"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imaResc"
    android:text="@string/numInvResc"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/idenResc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numInv"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numInv"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="@string/idenResc"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ubiResc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/idenResc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/idenResc"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="@string/ubiResc"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numHomResc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ubiResc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ubiResc"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="@string/numHomResc"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/matResc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numHomResc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numHomResc"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="@string/matResc"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numInvResCon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/idenResc"
    android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numInv"
    android:text="@string/vacia"
    android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/idenRescCont"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/idenResc"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numInvResCon"
    android:text="@string/vacia"
    android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ubiResCon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/numHomResc"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/idenRescCont"
    android:text="@string/vacia"
    android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numHomResCon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/matResc"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ubiResCon"
    android:text="@string/vacia"
    android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/matRescCon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/matResc"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/matResc"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numHomResCon"
    android:text="@string/vacia"
    android:textSize="@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imaResc"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imaResc"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imaResc"
    android:contentDescription="@string/guia"
    android:src="@drawable/barralat" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/matResc"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/barrahor" />

 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner1"
     style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/numInvResCon"
     android:layout_marginLeft="214dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numInvResCon"
     android:entries="@array/Equipos" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:entries="@array/Equipos" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tryed to put: `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` but it doesn't work, so y i've created a style in styles.xml:

```
 <style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_spinner_text_color</item>
    </style>
    <color name="my_spinner_text_color">#000000</color>
```

But the spinner remains invisible and i don't know do ...
can anyone help me?
I write this if help:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Thanks.

This is a screenShoot for eclipse: http://postimg.org/image/72utxtfin/

Comment: Show the java code where you inflate the View.

Comment: @JamesWierzba Thanks for your answer, i don´t inflate the view because i've used the array Equipos in the field entries. It's necessary inflate the view with java code when you use the field entries?

Comment: I mean the Activity, or Fragment, or whatever it is in your application that contains this view. It might not be "invisible" maybe it's simply not there. I can't know without some more context

Comment: This is the classical **@+id** issue. Simply remove the **+** from the relative references to an existing View.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i've wrote all xml file

Comment: @FrankN.Stein what + i have remove? this? <Spinner
     android:id="@id/spinner1"
     style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/numInvResCon"
     android:layout_marginLeft="214dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numInvResCon"
     android:entries="@array/Equipos" />

Comment: Every time you REFER to an EXISTING id, you don't have to put the **+**

Answer (score 0):

Try to set some width and height to spinner

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:entries="@array/Equipos" />
```

You set `wrap_content`

**Edit:**
I got this when i copy your code in Android Studio. So you can't see Spinner because it is out of screen.

[image: I got this when i copy your code in Android Studio. So you can't see Spinner because it is out of screen.]

Comment: thanks you very much but it doesn't work. I think probably it is a mistake relationated with app theme

Comment: Did you try to change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout with vertical orientation? Maybe some element cover another...No prob. we will find solution ;)

Comment: look this screenshot, maybe it could help you : http://postimg.org/image/72utxtfin/

Comment: if i push the screen it appears and i can choose an option, but if i don't push it is invisible

Comment: Maybe your views are too big. Try putting everything inside a scrollView

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi I've tryed the scrollView and it works as before, if i push in the screen i can choose an item but the spinner is invisible

Comment: @MilanNz my screen configuration is nexus 10, in my screen it works bien, finally i use a style: `<style name="Simple" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/letrasPequenasAumen</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item> </style> `

Comment: @user2070274 ok, i will try with nexus 10. Edit: i tried and everything is ok to me.. i can see spinner 1 and 2

Comment: the problem will be that mi app theme choose the background black and the spinner white, so i've changed the background to white the spinner looks invisible